# Any way to make `#` work in the URL on Github pages?

Tags: angularjs, github, github-pages

Any way to make `#` work in the URL on Github pages?

Using an angular setup it will hide the `#` in the URL. Github works when clicking thru, but not when refreshing or directly linking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

See http://kirkstrobeck.github.io/

http://kirkstrobeck.github.io/gettingStarted
vs
http://kirkstrobeck.github.io/#/gettingStarted

Comment: What do you want to use them for? For fragment linking like in the old days?

Comment: Angular routing http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, solved it using [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) rather than `ng-route`.

Comment: Any chance you could demonstrate on a fork or code snippet of http://vesparny.github.io/ng-kickstart ?